# What are the main principles of the Bacteriological Code?

Tags: microbiology, taxonomy, phylogenetics

Although the Bacteriological Code is an important guideline for taxonomists and microbiologists, describing the criteria for delineating species and higher taxa of the prokaryotes, I, and plenty of other microbiologists with me, would not be able to describe the main rules by heart. I am also not able to find a clear summary anywhere on the web, and reading and understanding the Code itself is currently taking quite some time.

Furthermore, does the Code say anything about taxa mainly or solely composed of uncultured strains based on 16S sequences, apart from the addition of *Candidatus* to currently uncultured single species? I am specifically referring to higher taxa, large groups of sequences.